# Ubuntu live CD doesn't show Macintosh HD

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, mac, sata, hfs+

I started Kubuntu 14.04 from USB on my Macbook Pro (2011) with OS X Lion (10.7) but I cannot find the internal HDD.

It doesn't show up in the file browser (I think Dolphin) and not on the console with:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

`fdisk` only shows the USB drive.

I also installed `hfsutils` and `gparted` inside the live environment and checked there. No luck either, so I decided that the HD must be broken and dismantled it to check in my external USB SATA Adapter.

See there: The Disk works on my other laptop with the USB SATA Adapter.

So how can I mount the Mac HDD inside the Live Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wouldn't be anything special to do to mount a HFS+ formatted harddrive in the Ubuntu live environment.

The drivers are included and the drive will be mounted read only by default.

If the drive doesn't show up, it is either defect or something else is wrong with your hardware.

*In my case it turned out, that the disk wasn't shown because the SATA cable was broken.*